# Regex matching text in brackets over multiple lines

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

```
node [
    id 2
    label "node 2"
    thisIsASampleAttribute 43
]
node [
    id 3
    label "node 3"
    thisIsASampleAttribute 44
]
```

And I want to group each node and its content inside the brackets e.g:

```
    node [
    id 2
    label "node 2"
    thisIsASampleAttribute 43
]
```

However I'm grouping the entire text with my following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("node \\[\n(.*|\n)*?\\]", Pattern.MULTILINE);

Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Edit text:

```
    node [\n" +
"       id 2\n" +
"       label \"node 2\"\n" +
"       thisIsASampleAttribute 43\n" +
"   ]\n" +
"   node [\n" +
"       id 3\n" +
"       label \"node 3\"\n" +
"       thisIsASampleAttribute 44\n" +
"   ]\n"
```

Comment: Do you have enough slashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are only capturing the last character with `(.*|\n)*?` (because `.?` isn't inside of the capturing group).

You could change the capturing group to a non-capturing group and then wrap that and `*?` with a capturing group in order to capture all the matches `((?:.*?|\n)*?)`.

[**Example Here**](http://ideone.com/BarOIZ)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("node \\[\\n((?:.*?|\\n)*?)\\]", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

---

However, the regular expression above is relatively inefficient. A potentially better approach would be to match non-`]` characters with a negated character set, `([^\]]*)`.

[**Example Here**](http://ideone.com/66zUJd)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("node \\[\\n([^\\]]*)\\]", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in Java, but why does it need just one slash in `\n` and two slashes in `\\[` ?

Comment: seems to still be grouping everything. I've updated the question with the text that has the characters if that helps

Comment: @joe I added examples.. are you retrieving the first capturing group? `m.group(1)`?